# yum list installed including version of all installed packages CentOS 5.4

Tags: centos, web-server, configuration, bash, yum

I have a list of packages installed with yum on CentOS 5.4

```
[root@server ~]# yum list installed
...
Installed Packages
GConf2.x86_64             2.14.0-9.el5           installed
ImageMagick.x86_64        6.2.8.0-4.el5_1.1      installed
MAKEDEV.x86_64            3.23-1.2               installed
MySQL-python.x86_64       1.2.1-1                installed
```

I would like to download these `rpm`s locally using

`yumdownloader --resolve MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64` etc.

However the package formatting is different (`MySQL-python.x86_64       1.2.1-1` vs `MySQL-python-1.2.1-1.x86_64`) so I am unable to download them using the above command.

I don't want to have to parse the output of `yum list installed`, and I also don't want to use the contents of `/var/log/yum.log*` as I'll have to account for erased packages and version discrepancies. However `/var/log/yum.log*` does have the formatting I require...

```
May 25 14:58:15 Installed: groff-1.18.1.1-11.1.x86_64
May 25 14:58:15 Installed: bzip2-1.0.3-4.el5_2.x86_64
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use rpm to list the installed rpms and format the output:

```
rpm -qa --qf "%{NAME}-%{VERSION}-%{RELEASE}.%{ARCH}\n"
```